# Redmine EVM plugin is not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redmine, bitnami, redmine-plugins

Im a redmine user.EVM plugin in redmine is not working when the banner is enabled.Anyone please tell how to resolve this issue ?

```
 Started GET "/redmine/admin/plugins" for 10.222.185.22 at 2014-03-10 06:42:05 +0000
  Processing by AdminController#plugins as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered admin/plugins.html.erb within layouts/admin (10.8ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (12.7ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_project_body_bottom.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_body_bottom.html.erb (8.2ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_after_top_menu.html.erb (9.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (45.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 80.7ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
Started GET "/redmine/settings/plugin/redmine_banner" for 10.222.185.22 at 2014-03-10 06:42:09 +0000
Processing by SettingsController#plugin as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"redmine_banner"}
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/settings/_redmine_banner.html.erb (10.2ms)
  Rendered plugins/scrum2b/app/views/settings/plugin.html.erb within layouts/admin (11.9ms)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (5.9ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_project_body_bottom.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_body_bottom.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_after_top_menu.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (18.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 43ms (Views: 37.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
Started GET "/redmine/admin" for 10.222.185.22 at 2014-03-10 06:45:54 +0000
Processing by AdminController#index as HTML
  Current user: admin (id=1)
  Rendered admin/_menu.html.erb (13.4ms)
  Rendered admin/index.html.erb within layouts/admin (14.8ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_project_body_bottom.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_body_bottom.html.erb (7.7ms)
  Rendered plugins/redmine_banner/app/views/banner/_after_top_menu.html.erb (8.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/base.html.erb (41.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 57.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? can you provide the logs?

Comment: Hai Below given is the log..Please check it and provide a solution

Comment: Log does not have any errors. What is wrong and what does not work?

Comment: It's taking too  much time to open the evm.And EVM is not properly responding too.

Comment: Does any body please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also face the same issue during my Redmine initial setup stage.There are many possible reasons.
1)This might be due to a data discrepancy.Change your `mysql` dump and try again.

2)Check whether `proxy` is set in the server.Otherwise it won't fetch data from google maps and charts will not get generated.

3)Other possibility is plugin compatibility.A new version of `EVM` plugin is available in Git.Please download and install it and try again.https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/redmine_evm

Comment: @Raj: Thanks, I have installed the new plugin.and it is working fine :)